# Where is the data in array going?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, processing

I have a Processing sketch, where I am trying to just draw a scatter plot of a dataset I'm working with. I'm loading the .CSV file into an array no problem, and I'm able to format it all and throw it into a "tokens" array in order to access info in a specific row.

The problem seems to be after I parse the data, and try to map the information in order to draw the graph, all the elements in the array return 0.0.

The code is a little lengthy, but I'll just try and keep it to the relevant bits, and hopefully not leave anything out.

```
void setup(){
size(1024, 768)
smooth();

OfficinaBold36 = loadFont("OfficinaBold-36.vlw");

//Load data
googleData     = loadStrings("RobFordCorrelate.csv");

//Init all the arrays 
if((googleData == null){
println("Error, one of the datasets could not be loaded.");
}
else{

     totalSearch      = googleData.length-1;
     googleDates      = new int[totalSearch];
     relativeInterest = new float[totalSearch];

     //Also grabbing all column names for use later, if needed
     columnNames      = googleData[0].split(",");
 }

parseGoogleData();
}
```

This the parseGoogleData function:

```
void parseGoogleData(){

/*Grab all the dates, we have to loop backwards through this set,
because the CSV was formatted in reverse chronological order.

Note that because of the row > 0 condition, we will not include
row 0, i.e the column title row */

for (int row = googleData.length-1 ; row > 0; row--){

 /*counter going up, we need a reference to a counter that
 counts up, while the main index counts down, to be
 able to assign certain values*/
 int i = 0;

 //Grab all the elements in that row, splitting them at the comma
 googleTokens = googleData[row].split(",");

 // Grab the elements we want to look at, the date, index 0
 googleDates[i]      = int(googleTokens[0]);

 //and relative interest in the search term  "rob ford", index 1
 relativeInterest[i] = float(googleTokens[1]);


 //increment our 2nd counter
 i++;
 }
}
```

Also the relativeInterest array is a global variable, so I have access to it in both setup and draw. Now if I `println(relativeInterest[i])` in that last for loop, it will return all the proper data. However, if I print it in the draw() loop below, they all return zero (I'm only including the lines that refer to drawing each point, as I have a lot of positioning data for the x and y-axis that I didn't want to include):

```
void draw(){
for(int row = 0 ; row < totalSearch; row++){
float y = map(relativeInterest[row], -3, 3, 0, width);
float x = row*lb;

int d = 5;

noStroke();
fill(#FFBA00, 180);
ellipse(x, y, d, d);
}
```

When I run this code, each ellipse is in the exact same y position, I have no idea when the data in the array is getting set to 0? The stuff in the draw loop isn't accessing the array until these lines hit, but I don't know why they're being converted to 0.0?

Any/all help is greatly appreciated. Sorry for such a long post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `int i = 0;` outside of your for loop. Also you want `Integer.valueOf` and `Float.valueOf`, not `int()` and `float()` respectively.

Comment: Thank you! So I've sort of figured the `float()` conversion was chopping  off the extra 0's. I'm still new to a lot of this, so sorry for the dumb follow up question, why did I need to move the `int i = 0` outside the for loop?

Comment: otherwise it would reset to 0 every time.